# Custom Search Suggestions in Search Widget

Tags: android, search, android-searchmanager

I am using a **search widget** in my application.I want to provide the search suggestions with the **person names in the server**.  How to provide custom search suggestions where the names are retrieved from a **webservice**?

What are the steps i need to follow here?

Comment: [Show us some of your effort](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 1):

How about these links to get you started, [Android Search Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html) and [How to add search functionality to your Android application](http://matthias.jimdo.com/2011/06/06/how-to-add-search-functionality-to-your-android-application/).